# Iterate through an array using foreach in php

Tags: php

Does the following code work in php4

```
foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
    print "$i {\n";
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        print "    $key => $value\n";
    }
    print "}\n";
}
```

This works with php5 but the same loop with no changes does not work with the version 4.
The foreach iterates through the loop but the values are not displayed.
Could someone help me with this

Comment: How the $array is structured?

Comment: Wy do you even bother about PHP4? It's outdated and not supported version of PHP. Every shared hosting provides PHP5 (it's 8-yrs old!).

Comment: just tried on an old 4.4 php installation: it works fine.

Comment: For me, the reason is a big ball of muddy php4 code I have to maintain since 2001

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine in PHP 4 there is nothing PHP 5 specific there.

It is more likely your array is different in between the 2 versions. As we can't see the entire code its difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Should work in php4 as well:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
    echo $i."{\n";
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        echo $key ."=>". $value."\n";
    }
    echo "}\n";
}
```